# Using datamaps, I am trying to create a map with not 100% opacity

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, datamaps

I'm using datamaps (http://datamaps.github.io/) and trying to make the map transparent. I cannot find a built in feature for fillOpacity for the countries, only for the bubbles.

Since this is built on top of D3 I was wondering if there is a hacky workaround to achieve my goal. Eventually I'll probably switch over to D3 for the control.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default fill color with an RGBA value where the A (alpha) is used for transparency/ opacity. The main Github [page](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps) for datamaps currently has demo code for that, for example:

```js
const opacity = 0.2;
const map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('container'),
  fills: {
    defaultFill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```